# Markov Process and Exponential Growth Rate: is this a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, martingales, markov-process

Suppose we have a Markov process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$, taking values on $\mathcal{N}$, with this Q-matrix (Example 17.27 of Probability Theory, 3rd version, by A. Klenke):
$$
q(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } y=x+1\\ 
-x &\text{if } y=x\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

**Is $W_t=e^{-t}X_t$ a martingale?**

I know that $P_1[X_t>e^tx]=(1-e^{-t})^{\lfloor e^tx\rfloor}$ from a previous result in the same book above. To prove if it is a martingale, I am thinking about the trick about the expected value of a positive random variable but with no success.

I would also like to know if the time growth was linear, how could I spot it?

Let me know if more context is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $Q$-matrix you can show that $X_t-\int_0^t X_s\,ds$ is a martingale. Then by Ito's formula you see that $e^{-t}X_t$ is indeed a martingale.

**Added at OP's request:** Given a function $f$ on the state space, define $g(i):=\sum_{j\in\mathcal N} q(i,j)f(j)$. One way to think about the $Q$-matrix is this: $f(X_t)-\int_0^t g(X_s)\,ds$ is a martingale. For your $Q$-matrix, if $f(i) = i$ is the identity function, then $g(i)=i$ as well, by direct computation.

Another way to get at the martingale property of $e^{-t}X_t$ is as follows. For $t\ge 0$ and small $h>0$, we have
$$
\eqalign{E[e^{-(t+h)}X_{t+h}\mid \mathcal F_t]
&=e^{-(t+h)}\left[(X_t+1)\cdot(hX_t+o(h))+X_t\cdot(1-hX_t+o(h))\right]\cr
&=e^{-t}\cdot(1-h+o(h))\left[X_t\cdot(1+h)+o(h)\right]\cr
&=e^{-t}[X_t+o(h)].\cr
}
$$
Now to compute $E[e^{-t}X_t\mid \mathcal F_s]$, cut the interval $[s,t]$ into $n$ subintervals of length $\delta:=(t-s)/n$ and "telescope", using the tower property of conditional expectations:
$$
\eqalign{
E[e^{-t}X_t-e^{-s}X_s\mid\mathcal F_s]
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}E[e^{-(s+(k+1)\delta}X_{s+(k+1)\delta}-e^{-(s+k\delta)}X_{s+k\delta}\mid\mathcal F_s]\cr
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}E\left[E[e^{-(s+(k+1)\delta}X_{s+(k+1)\delta}-e^{-(s+k\delta)}X_{s+k\delta}\mid\mathcal F_{s+k\delta}]\,\mid \mathcal F_s\right]\cr
}
$$
Each inner conditional expectation in this final sum is $o(1/n)$ by what has gone before; therefore the sum is $n\cdot o(1/n) = o(1)$. Send $n\to\infty$ to see that $E[e^{-t}X_t-e^{-s}X_s\mid\mathcal F_s]=0$, which is the martingale property.

A good place to learn more about the martingale connection to the $Q$-matrix might be the book *Continuous Time Markov Processes* by T. Liggett.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Could you articulate a little bit more, especially about how to show that $X_t-\int_0^t X_s ds$ is a martingale? Also, is there another way to prove it? Ito's formula comes later in the cited book that I am studying.

Comment: Superb! One question: what the integral $ \int_0^t g(X_s)ds$ is doing? Is it summing up the process' values? The alternative way to prove that $W_t$ is a martingale is clear to me except for one step: how did you group the terms in this way $e^{-t}\cdot(1-h+o(h))\left[X_t\cdot(1+h)+o(h)\right]$ in the second equality? Thank you.

Comment: The $e^{-t}$ just factors out. For the rest I just distributed and collected terms. Things like $h^2$ and $ho(h)$ are $o(h)$, etc.